# Android using a string resource on preferences.xml file

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-settings

I'm trying to use android preferences api to save some configurations of my app.
Is there any way to use a value from `string.xml` as a key to preferences? ex:

```
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_sms_storage_title"
        android:key="@string/pref1">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="@string/pref2"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_auto_delete"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_auto_delete"
            android:defaultValue="false" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When i do this if i try to read the values like:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Boolean b = preferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref2),false);
```

it always returns `false`, even when it is set to `true`

I noticed that if I put the literal value on `key` field it works like:

```
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="something"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_auto_delete"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_auto_delete"
            android:defaultValue="false" />


Boolean b = preferences.getBoolean("something",false);
```

this case `b` returns true as expeted...

Is the official approach to use preferences API to copy paste string literals to preferences.xml?

Isn't there any other way less prone to mistakes?

Comment: String resource is supported in preferences.xml, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2857121/971070), maybe there are some other bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following simple example:

1) MnnnnActivity.class:-----------------

```
public class MnnnnActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button b;
private TextView tv;
private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout4);

    String preferenceName = getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key);

    preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(preferenceName,
            0);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MnnnnActivity.this , prefAct.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(preferences != null && tv != null){
        tv.setText("Changed to " + String.valueOf(preferences.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.pref2) , false)));
    }


}
}
```

2) prefAct.class:--------

```
public class prefAct extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    EditPrefs mEditPrefs= new EditPrefs();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mEditPrefs);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

3) EditPrefs.class:------------

```
public class EditPrefs extends PreferenceFragment implements  SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

private int preferencesToEdit;

private PreferenceHelper sensor_preferences;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String preferenceName = getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key);

    preferencesToEdit = R.xml.pr;

    PreferenceManager preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
    preferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesName(preferenceName);
    preferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesMode(0);

    getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_sensor_action_bar_title));// TODO:change this

    addPreferencesFromResource(preferencesToEdit);

}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {


    if (findPreference(key) != null) {

        if (findPreference(key).getKey().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.pref2))) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Changed to " + sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.pref2), false), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if(view != null) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

}
```

4) layout4.xml:--------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Click"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:text="x"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

5) pr.xml:---------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory>

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="@string/pref2"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_auto_delete"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_auto_delete"
        android:defaultValue="false" />

</PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

6) string resources:--------

```
<string name="pref_key">pref_key</string>
<string name="pref2">pref2</string>
<string name="pref_title_auto_delete">title</string>
<string name="pref_summary_auto_delete">summary</string>
```

7) Don't forget to include both activities in the manifest.

Comment: what you are doing is really wrong, you trying to rewrite the whole preference framework android has built in